# sas sense key data protect

Tags: sas, scsi

I have several Hitachi Ultrastar SSD400M Model #HUSML4040ASS601. They had a block size of 520 and I was able to successfully format all but one of them using sg_utils' sg_format to 512. However, one of the drives reports "sense key data protect".

Is a way to disable data protect on the drive?

Comment: Operating system? RAID controller? SAS controller? Server hardware? You're missing some details.

Comment: O/S  is Centos 7, Controller is LSI 9211-8i, Server is HP DL385 G5.